# Versioning an angular application in production

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have multi module application, where some of my modules are lazily loaded, and so the output files in dist folder looks like this 1.d2ef1******8da.chunk.js, 2.dsfd3******8da.chunk.js and like wise. The problem is, if I create a new build for the production, then the hash changes and so the file names. Suppose a user has not refreshed the page, they still will try to lazily load the old file which will be shown as file not found. In such case my page hangs. How should I handle it ?

Comment: You should use Angular service worker to achieve that.  read more about it here: https://angular.io/guide/service-worker-getting-started

Answer (score 5):

You can make use of Angular Service Workers to change your app into  a **PWA** (Progressive Web Application).

It makes use of angular service workers to alert users to reload if a new version of app is deployed.

For Ex:

1. Install `@angular/service-worker`, add it to `package.json` and install dependencies.
2. Import `ServiceWorkerModule` in AppModule:

   ```
   import { ServiceWorkerModule } from '@angular/service-worker';
   ```
3. Register it in the AppModule imports array:

   ```
   ServiceWorkerModule.register('ngsw-worker.js', { enabled: environment.production })
   ```
4. Use it in app root component:

   ```
   import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
   import { SwUpdate } from "@angular/service-worker";


   export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

   constructor(private swUpdate: SwUpdate){}

   ngOnInit(): void {
       if (this.swUpdate.isEnabled) {
         this.swUpdate.available.subscribe(() => {
           if (confirm("A New version of site is available. Load New Version?")) {
             window.location.reload();
           }
         });
       }
     }
   }
   ```

If you are on angular 4 and cli ~1.6. The process should be same.

- `npm install @angular/service-worker`
- add it in App Module as explained above
- create a `ngsw-config.json` file in your app’s src directory.

  ```
  {
   "index": "/index.html",
    "assetGroups": [{
    "name": "app",
    "installMode": "prefetch",
    "resources": {
    "files": [
      "/favicon.ico",
      "/index.html"
    ],
    "versionedFiles": [
      "/*.bundle.css",
      "/*.bundle.js",
      "/*.chunk.js"
    ]
  }
  }, {
   "name": "assets",
   "installMode": "lazy",
   "updateMode": "prefetch",
    "resources": {
     "files": [
       "/assets/**"
      ]
     }
   }]
  }
  ```
- Trying it Out
  With the configuration in place, we can build the app for production (`ng build --prod`) and test it out using a local static server using -
  `npx http-server /dist`

Comment: Thanks a lot. I am using Angular: 4.4.6, can you please suggest something related to that.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the steps apart from #4 above are done automatically by latest angular cli command (https://angular.io/api/service-worker):
ng add @angular/pwa