# How to force all clients get the newer version of my web application

Tags: angular, html

Our software is deployed by Angular 6 and C# WebApi. We are using ng build --prod to deploy and cli generate the random file name. I also have no-cache meta tag on HTML pages. But the problem is many of our users does not close their tabs and when we deploy new changes the back-end changes will affect the server. But the front code does not match. As soon as they close the tab and reopen they will get the newer version. But I want to make it automatic to update their front-end code. any idea about that?

```
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache" />
```

Comment: The pattern I have seen for this is to pack your version numbers in a header in all of your requests. Then when a packet comes in that is a version mismatch, trigger cache reset (or request the user refresh).

Comment: this can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54292391/9386929
Also, many build tools now seamlessly incorporate cache-busting and file "versioning" techniques to address this. WebPack is arguably the current leader in this space.

Comment: That's precisely what I was going to suggest @nircraft: convert your app to a PWA with SW and [handle the update event](https://angular.io/guide/service-worker-devops).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Versioning an angular application in production](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54288446/versioning-an-angular-application-in-production)

Comment: You can use a 404 or error page to guide user (by clicking button, links...) to reload your app.

Comment: Use PWA in Angular cli , it has good support in Angular 6+